# How to get the popup long text Aligned even in Zoom in and Zoom out? - LWC Component

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, slds, html5

> This Image is when I clicked on Button and it showed popup with any zooming.
> [image]
> This image is when I zooming under 100%. Could you please suggest how to show the popup with text without split. I am trying to assign Style on the div and even in css but it still doesn't consider that : `
> [image]

```
      **

 - CSS Code Block:

**
    .slds-form-element__label {
        word-wrap: break-word;
        hyphens: inherit !important;
        display: inline-block;
        color: var(--lwc-colorTextLabel,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
        padding-right: var(--lwc-spacingXSmall,0.5rem);
        padding-top: var(--lwc-spacingXxSmall,0.25rem);
        margin-bottom: var(--lwc-spacingXxxSmall,0.125rem);
    }



DIV code:
    <div class="slds-large-size_12-of-12 slds-medium-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size_12-of-12 slds-p-around_large slds-form-element__label" style="hyphens:inherit">
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad!! Actually VScode was not deploying the code so now problem is resolved.